# Remove user name from table name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-schema

I restored a database after a server failure and now I'm running into a problem where the table names show as `database_user_name.table_name`. So when I query something like:

```
select * from contacts
```

it doesn't work because it expects it be fully qualified, as in:

```
select * from user1000.contacts
```

The problem with this is that I have hundreds of stored procedures that reference the tables with their name, so none of the queries work.

Is there a way to tell SQL Server 2005 to drop the username from the table without changing the user as the owner?

Answer (score 2):

try this advice from the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx):

> To change the schema of a table or view by using SQL Server Management Studio, in Object Explorer, right-click the table or view and then click Design. Press F4 to open the Properties window. In the Schema box, select a new schema.

Comment: If there are 100 tables, this won't be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure none of the tables exist in the `dbo` schema as well, then you can say:

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER user1000.contacts;
```

To generate a set of scripts for all of the tables in that schema, you can say:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER user1000.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
  FROM sys.tables
  WHERE SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) = N'user1000';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(Once you're happy with the `PRINT` output - acknowledging that it will be truncated at 8K even though the variable really contains the whole script - uncomment the `EXEC` and run it again. This does not check for potential conflicts.)

But the real fix is to fix your code. You should never say `select * from contacts` - both the * and [the missing schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) can be problematic for various reasons.